# Exposing Entity Framework extensions to a Service Layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I've implemented my Data layer using the `IRepository` pattern. One of these methods returns an `IQueryable`:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable()
{
        return dbSet;
}
```

I also have a Service layer that calls this method that supplies filtering e.g.:

```
public User GetByName(string name)
{
    return _repository.Queryable()
        .Where(a => a.Name == name)
        .ToList();
}
```

So far so good, Entity Framework is only referenced in the data layer, the Service layer knows nothing about this.

Now, however I want to do two additional things:

1. Use the `Include` method
2. Use `ToListAsync()` method

So now my service method looks like this:

```
public async Task<User> GetByName(string name)
{
    return await _repository.Queryable()
        .Where(a => a.Name == name)
        .Include(x => x.Pets)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

The issue now is that both `Include()` and `ToListAsync()` are both in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace which is in the `EntityFramework.dll`.

I didn't want to reference EF from within my Service layer, it shouldn't care or know about this, but can't see how else to solve this while keep the architecture clean. The only solutions I can see are:

1. Add Entity Framework to Service layer
2. Add a new class to Data layer (`UserData`) that wraps `IRepository<User>' and handles the two additional methods required. The service will then take use an instance of this rather than`IRepository`.

Any suggestions about how I solve this while still adhering to best practices?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of abstracting away EF, if you're just going to expose a call that will allow the business layer to write its own queries.  It makes the repository feel kind of worthless to me.  Not really related to the question, I'm just curious what the logic is there.

Comment: I feel like the `Include` part should really be in the repository.  Essentially the repository should know what to return in terms of the object graph, and those operations should simply support the business needs of any use cases.  Would be nice if `ToListAsync` was outside of EF, I agree.  Though I guess I don't know enough about its implementation to know if it would even make sense outside of EF.

Comment: Why exactly you use repository except of "best practicies", what is the reasoning? Maybe you expect to cache results or something.

Comment: [Whenever expose `IQueryable` you force the consumer of your API to have intimate knowledge of the implementation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/). You might as well add a reference to EF.

Comment: would love an update on this even if someone has a gd link to read.As i find im always torn between what even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to abstract away EF in the repository layer, based on best practices.  But your use cases (your main question here) is a contradiction of that - you want to expose everything that EF offers to your service layer.

It sounds like you need to define a strict line as to what the responsibility of this repository is.  If it's to return an `IQueryable`, then what is the benefit of wrapping EF at all?  Is there some other repository implementation you plan to actually use in production?  If so, it's going to be very hard to ensure both repo types are correct, when you expose `IQueryable`.  This is the pain point that you are seeing right now.

In my opinion, a repository should define how you get data.  It should expose simple calls like `GetAllUsers` that returns actual models.  When you let the business/service layer define its own way to get the data, it makes the repository feel redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Include and ToListAsync live in EF, therefore they should be kept in the EF service.

The only way to access these without having to provide a reference to System.Entity is to create your own proxy methods. At the end of the day you should code to what your application requires at a high level rather than making sure it can access everything EF can.

When I deal with EF, I create a Service/Context layer, a repository layer and then a client layer which abstracts away the EF technicalities. This is then user by other devs/users so they aren't exposed too much to the EF side of things. I just workout what is required by the app and implement methods to do just that and nothing more. There is little point bringing the functions of System.Entity beyond the DAL, they should be abstracted away at client level.

One thing I do hate though is having to duplicate models if I want to keep my service/context layer away from other parts of the application. To get around this I have a model factory which uses DI to find the EF models and deliver them via a DI container. It just means I have to add an interface to each model I create. No biggie.